# How do I get my 'logo' image to show in the header?

Tags: html, css, image

I'm very, very new to HTML and CSS, so sorry for my ignorance! I'm trying to add an image to my header, to go to the left and above the navigation. Any help anyone can give would be amazing!!

I have tried two ways of adding the image, the first using , but it did not show (I could see the image 'content' highlighted in blue on the page when i was in the console, but i couldn't see the image. The second way I used a , then the css below:

```
body {
    background-color:#4A4849;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-family:Arial, helvetica, sans-serif;    
}

.Logo {         
        display: inline;
        float:left;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-image: url('../Images/Logo.png');
}

header {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 15%;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0;
}
```

My full CSS includes the below...i feel like the problem is to do with the , as in the console the dimensions show as 1304x0 (but I am able to see the navigation) I therefore tried adjusting the header, which is why it duplicates with the .topnav.(see below)   :)

```
.topnav {
        font-weight: bold;
        background-color: white;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left 0;
        width:100%;
        height:15%;
       }

.topnav ul  {
        list-style-type:none;
        overflow: hidden;
        margin:0;
        padding: 0;
}

.topnav li  {
            display:inline;
            padding: 0px;
            margin: 0px;

            }

.topnav a {

        float: right;
        color: #4A4849;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 20px 10px;
        text-decoration:none;
        width:10%;
        }
```

It would be great if anyone could help, as I've tried different things based on resources i've found online!

*HTML, in case you need it:

```
<body>
  <header>
      <div class="Logo"></div>

    <nav>
      <div class="topnav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="Contact.html">CONTACT US</a></li>
            <li><a href="About.html">ABOUT US</a></li>
            <li><a href="GraphicDesign.html">GRAPHIC DESIGN</a></li>
            <li><a href="HouseArt.html">MARKET</a></li>
            <li><a href="Home.html">HOME</a></li>

        </ul>
      </div>

  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: A lot of these problems originate because of the file path being incorrect. Have you double-checked that? **Remember**: if you are trying to access a folder that is in the same directory you are currently in, there is no `../` or `/` before it. If that's not the case, try different `display` values.

Comment: Hi! Did you try to change `display: inline` to `display: inline-block` in the `.Logo` class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things that can be changed with how you are setting things up:

1. I would recommend not making your logo the `background-image` on a div, when an `<img>` tag will work better in your case (`<img src="path/to/your/logo.png">`).
2. If you do use it as a `background-image` on a div, you have to remember that background images do not affect the height of an element.
3. Setting a `%` height on the `.Logo` div will also not work, since a percentage height needs to be relative to a containing element and you also set it to an `inline` element (height will not apply). Since, its parent (`header`) has as height of `15%`, but that element also has no reference to `15%` - e.g. 15% of what? The body tag would need to have a height set to `100%`.

Only for your logo, I would simply do this:

```html
<header>
    <img src="your logo link">

    <nav>
      <div class="topnav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="Contact.html">CONTACT US</a></li>
            <li><a href="About.html">ABOUT US</a></li>
            <li><a href="GraphicDesign.html">GRAPHIC DESIGN</a></li>
            <li><a href="HouseArt.html">MARKET</a></li>
            <li><a href="Home.html">HOME</a></li>

        </ul>
      </div>

  </nav>
</header>
```

If you absolutely want to make it a background-image:

```css
.Logo {
  height: whatever your logo height is;
  display: block;
  background-image: url( ../Images/logo.png );
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<header>
      <div class="Logo"></div>

    <nav>
      <div class="topnav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="Contact.html">CONTACT US</a></li>
            <li><a href="About.html">ABOUT US</a></li>
            <li><a href="GraphicDesign.html">GRAPHIC DESIGN</a></li>
            <li><a href="HouseArt.html">MARKET</a></li>
            <li><a href="Home.html">HOME</a></li>

        </ul>
      </div>

  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! this was really useful information! I've used the image tag as you recommended. it took a bit of playing around with the css to get it in the right position, but i think I've pretty much gotten there, so thanks for your advice. 

I'm worried about using percentages, i've set the body and html to height:100%, then the header, height:20%, main, height:65%, and footer, height:15% for now..
will this create issues later on? the reason i was wanting to  use percentages was because I had thought using pixels would effect how it looks on different sized screens.

Comment: Percentages for height are not very necessary (this is my opinion) for responsive sites - since content will usually stack/push down correctly. You should focus on the width of elements - which very much rely on percentages when developing for mobile.

Comment: Also, for those elements - `header`, `main` and `footer` - no reason to set heights - unless you are trying to do something very specific. Let the content dictate the height. Percentages for height can cause issues down the road if you are not trying to solve a particular issue.